# Overpass API AROUND filter doesn't work with small distances

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Given the coordinates ([55.8141015,26.8400810](https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=55.8141015%2C26.8400810#map=17/55.81430/26.84025)) I need to check if this location is inside a cemetery. My initial idea was that I would easily make such [request](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Jch):

```
(
    way[landuse=cemetery]
    (around:1,55.8141015,26.8400810);
);
out geom meta;
```

If this query returns me the cemetery, then these coordinates are inside it. But the problem, to my surprise, was that the query starts to return cemeteries only after increasing radius to 20 meters. And it returns 2 cemeteries!

How can I make an exact query by coordinates and list all areas that enclose this location?

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/86 - you need to set up your own Overpass API instance and modify the area creation rules. That's the only solution available today.